# FindBugs Ignores @Nullable

Tags: java, nullable, findbugs

I have a unit test where I deliberately pass a null parameter to a method, to verify that the method correctly detects the null. I added the @Nullable annotation to the parameter, but FindBugs complains that the (deliberate) null argument is an error. Here's the code:

```
@Test(expected = ApiDataError.class) public void dateNull() {
    try {
        @Nullable final Date date = null;
        ApiFault.check(date, TEST);
    } catch (final ApiDataError ex) {
        assertEquals(ex.getMessage(), format(ApiFault.NULL_VALUE, TEST));
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

FindBugs reports:

**Bug: Non-virtual method call in com.foo.test.ex.ApiFaultTests.dateNull() passes null for nonnull parameter of com.foo.commons.ex.error.ApiFault.check(Date, String)**

How can I make FindBugs stop crying wolf?

I use Eclipse Kepler, service release 2, with FindBugs 3.00.

Comment: Have you added `@Nullable` to the called method, too? Just putting it on the `date` variable as shown in your example has no effect. These annotations are intended to be used as part of the contract.

Comment: I'm going to respond one more time. Stackoverflow's brain dead formatting is killing me.

The filter file isn't working 

    <FindBugsFilter>
        <!-- Passing null is deliberate in this unit test -->
        <Match>
            <Class name="com.uprr.eni.commons.test.ex.ApiFaultTests" />
            <Method name="dateNull" />
            <Bug code="NP" />
        </Match>
    </FindBugsFilter>

Comment: FYI, Stack Overflow wants you to enter additional information in your question, not in the comments. This way, people reading your question find all information in one place. Just press *edit* under your question and add the filter file there.

Answer (score 3):

Use an [exclusion filter](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html) to tell FindBugs not to report the error when analyzing your unit test class. Your filter might look something like this:

```
<FindBugsFilter>
    <!-- Passing null is deliberate in this unit test-->
    <Match>
        <Class name="com.foo.test.ex.ApiFaultTests" />
        <Method name="dateNull" />
        <Bug code="NP" />
    </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

Comment: This is very frustrating. Here's my filter file (I hope):

Comment: I give up. The system seems determined to prevent me from entering anything substantive. Stack overflow sucks.

Comment: @AdamRichards Maybe try editing your question to include your filter? It might also be useful to show how you're invoking FindBugs.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the other posts for this question, I assume that your method under test expects the parameter to be non-null, but you want to pass `null` as part of this one unit test.

In that case, you can simply annotate the unit test method with `@SuppressFBWarnings`:

```java
@SuppressFBWarnings(value="NP_NONNULL_PARAM_VIOLATION",
    justification="testing nullness contract violation")
@Test(expected = ApiDataError.class)
public void dateNull() throws ApiDataError {
    final Date date = null;
    ApiFault.check(date, TEST);
}
```

Comment: For cases (like the OP's) where you can modify the source code, this looks like a better solution than using an external filter file.